# printing multiple values by listing their keys

Tags: python, dictionary, encryption

```
Encrypt_2 = {'y': 'a', 'z': 'b', 'a': 'c', 'b': 'd', 'c': 'e', 'd': 'f', 'e': 'g', 'f': 'h', 'g': 'i', 'h': 'j', 'i': 'k', 'j': 'l', 'k': 'm', 'l': 'n', 'm': 'o', 'n': 'p', 'o': 'q', 'p': 'r', 'q': 's', 'r': 't', 's': 'u', 't': 'v', 'u': 'w', 'v': 'x', 'w': 'y', 'x': 'z'}

##printing encrypted text

Encrypt_2['f', 'c', 'j', 'j', 'm']
```

Note: Will get syntax error, I am trying to find an easier way to print multiple values by listing their keys.

I know the standard ways of print key values would be
Encrypt_2['f'], Encrypt_2['c'], Encrypt_2['j']..........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try a for loop

```
for i in ['f', 'c', 'j', 'j', 'm']:

    print(Encrypt_2[i])
```

```
>>> hello
```

Answer (score 3):

what you could try is:

```
keys = ['f', 'c', 'j', 'j', 'm'] # or keys='fcjjm'
```

and then loop through that list and get the value for each key

```
values = [Encrypt_2[x] for x in keys]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are 4 ways of doing it. Note that with number 4, 97 is `ord('a')` and does not require any dictionary to work (since you are doing the same operation the each character (shifting it 2 along), there isn't much reason to make a large dictionary to represent it).

```
encrypt_2 = {'y': 'a', 'z': 'b', 'a': 'c', 'b': 'd', 'c': 'e', 'd': 'f', 'e': 'g', 'f': 'h', 'g': 'i', 'h': 'j', 'i': 'k', 'j': 'l', 'k': 'm', 'l': 'n', 'm': 'o', 'n': 'p', 'o': 'q', 'p': 'r', 'q': 's', 'r': 't', 's': 'u', 't': 'v', 'u': 'w', 'v': 'x', 'w': 'y', 'x': 'z'}

def convert_text1(string):
    characters = [] # empty list where we will put values
    for char in string:
        # 'char' represents the current character in the string
        characters.append(encrypt_2[char])
    return ''.join(characters)
    # each characters is joined, separated by an empty string
    # e.g. ['a', 'b', 'c'] to 'abc'

def convert_text2(string):
    return ''.join(encrypt_2[char] for char in string)

def convert_text3(string):
    return ''.join(map(encrypt_2.__getitem__, string))

def convert_text4(string):
    return ''.join(chr((ord(char) + 2 - 97) % 26 + 97) for char in string)
```